# Proof in the style: Show that exists an $\epsilon$ st $X$ is true

Tags: logic, epsilon-delta

there's example from the logic appendix from Tao's Analysis 1 Book with the aim of clarify how you can do proof of existence of an $\epsilon$ st a property $P(x)$ is true.

The thereom and the proof are:[image]
[image]

I don't quite understand what the author meant with the phrase in green. It should have something to do with the fact we have to proof for the chosen  $\epsilon$ that $P(x)$ is true for a infinite values of $x$ (inside the interval). But I am not fully understanding this.

And other thing: Note the author states that "if we had chosen $\epsilon$ to depend on $x$ **and** $y$ then the argument..." What does he meant by that? If my $\epsilon$ it's only function of $x$ then we would have no problem here?

Comment: The statement proven has the form $\exists\epsilon\forall x ...$. Therefore the choice of $\epsilon$ must not depend on $x$. If the form had been $\forall x\exists\epsilon ...$, then $\epsilon$ *could* depend on $x.$

Comment: @symplectomorphic one way to understand this, is because I pick an $\epsilon$ first and then I chose an arbitrary $x$. So  $\epsilon$ can not depend on $x$ because I dont know what $x$ is in principle. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the right idea for $\exists\epsilon\forall x ...$. More to the point: you must pick an $\epsilon$ that works for *all* $x$, no matter which $x$. So $\epsilon$ cannot depend on $x$.